# How to rewrite $\frac{\partial \rho u_i u_j}{\partial x_j}$ in vector notation

Tags: tensors

I want to rewrite this index notation expression to a vector notation /symbolic notation.

$$\frac{\partial \rho u_i u_j}{\partial x_j}=\frac{\partial \rho }{\partial x_j}u_i u_j+\rho\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} u_j+\rho u_i\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_j} $$

This is what i have tried so far:

Expression 1:
$$=u_i\vec{u}\cdot\left(\nabla\rho\right)+\rho\vec{u}\cdot\left(\nabla\vec{u}\right)+\rho u_i\left(\nabla \cdot \vec{u}\right)$$

$$=u_i\left[\nabla \cdot\left(\rho\vec{u}\right)\right]+\rho\vec{u}\cdot\left(\nabla\vec{u}\right)$$

Expression 2:
$$=\nabla\cdot\left(\rho u_i \vec{u}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that I prefer index notation, that presents less ambiguities, I would write expression 1 as:
$$
\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla)\rho+\rho(\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{u}+\rho\mathbf{u}(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u})
$$
and expression 2 as
$$
\nabla\cdot(\rho\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{u})
$$

Comment: Thank you :). So it is like applying the $\cdot\nabla$ operator on every variale from right. The problem with index notation is, that it is tied to a coordinate system.